# Java JSP servlet can't see DB in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I begun to learn datebase and servlet, JSP. And I don't know some fails. I can't see my db in JSP.

**Java code:**

```
try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
        String sql = "select * fiz_phone";
        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
        s.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = s.getResultSet();
        while (rs.next()) {
            dataList.add(rs.getInt("id"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("name"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("adress"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("phone"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("phone_adress"));
            dataList.add(rs.getInt("cost"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("exempt_type"));
            dataList.add(rs.getInt("exempt"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("date_claim"));
            dataList.add(rs.getInt("number_claim"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("inspektor"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("date_repair"));
            dataList.add(rs.getInt("phone_cost"));
            dataList.add(rs.getString("call"));
        }
        rs.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);

    }

    request.setAttribute("data", dataList);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(page);

    if (dispatcher != null) {

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
   <body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td ><b>ID</b></td>
            <td ><b>Name</b></td>
            <td ><b>Adress</b></td>
            <td ><b>Phone</b></td>
            <td ><b>Phone adress</b></td>
            <td ><b>Cost</b></td>
            <td ><b>Exempt type</b></td>
            <td ><b>Exempt</b></td>
            <td ><b>Date claim</b></td>
            <td ><b>Number of claim</b></td>
            <td ><b>Inspektor</b></td>
            <td ><b>Date repair</b></td>
            <td ><b>Phone cost</b></td>
            <td ><b>Call</b></td>
    
    
        </tr>
        <%ArrayList<String> f = (ArrayList<String>) request
        .getAttribute("data");
        Iterator<String> itr = f.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {%>
    
        <tr id="tab">
    
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
    </table>
    </body>
```

and servlet

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>DataServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>work_project.Data</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DataServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/DataServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

When I start this program, it give me this exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /DataPage.jsp at line 35

32:     </tr>
33:     <%Iterator itr;%>
34:     <% List data= (List)request.getAttribute("data");
35:         for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
36:     %>
37:     <tr>
38:         <td ><%=itr.next()%></td>
```

Comment: What exception occur.post your complete stack trace.

Comment: If I understand you:

 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: It is not complete stack trace.Actual exception not here.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c621318/v621318101/5d91/Gwaq7dRvpzM.jpg

Look at this picture please.

Comment: Can you show me your complete code of servlet.

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c621318/v621318101/5dc0/w6kM1yvuDfc.jpg

Comment: Your servlet class does not look right `word_project.Data`. Is that really the name of your servlet class?

Comment: @Susie 
Yes, I must add name of my project and then name of class java
Isn't correct?

Comment: Your servlet class is the class of your servlet. What is the name of the class your code above is in? The code that has `try{` block

Answer (score 0):

I ran an example of your code. It worked. The only difference was that I inserted some code into the data list, instead of accessing a database. Even if the result set was empty, you should not be getting a null pointer exception.

Since you are getting a null pointer exception when you access the data list, it seems to indicate that the original list in the servlet was null. What is the code for instantiating the dataList in the servlet? Do you have a statement somewhere like

```
List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Try debugging your code. Set a breakpoint in the servlet on the setAtribute statement. See if dataList is null.

Also check that the loop is executing. Be sure the result set is not empty.

Comment: Yes, of course. I can to show
https://pp.vk.me/c621318/v621318101/5e50/U_2o18htCfI.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The code should be a valid SQL query by querying a database with JDBC statement.

```
String sql = "select * from fiz_phone";
```

It might be a typo but you ignored it in the code for the catch block

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    //TODO you should handle the exception here
    System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);

}
```

Also since you are learning, you better return an object for each record from the resultset.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    obj.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    ...

    dataList.add(obj);
}
```

Also do it in iterator

```
<%ArrayList<MyObject> f = (ArrayList<MyOobject>) request.getAttribute("data");
Iterator<MyObject> itr = f.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  MyObject obj = itr.next();
  pageContext.setAttribute("row", obj);%>

<tr id="tab">
    <td >${row.id}</td>
    <td >$(row.name}</td>
    ...
</tr>
<%} pageContext.removeAttribute("row");%>
```

You should make `MyObject` a java bean (i.e. properties should have getters and setters). Latter you may try to remove scriptlets at all by using JSTL tag library and `forEach` tag.

Comment: Thank you so much.I did it like a your code. But it doesn't work.
Exception again.
And in this sentence 
work_project.Base row = itr.next();  %>

Program doesn't see "row". 

https://pp.vk.me/c621318/v621318101/5e62/xyrCspFUl0s.jpg

Comment: The `row` should be set to any scope (i.e. page) to be searchable by expression.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer of Roman C, the scriptlet scope is not the same as the expression language scope. If you use a jstl core template for the loop, then it should see row.

```
  <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
  <c:forEach var="row" items="${data}">
    <tr id="tab">
        <td >${row.id}</td>
        <td >${row.name}</td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

I do not think this will resolve the original problem. data is probably still null.

Have you tried using the debugger and testing that dataList is not null when it is added to the request with setAttribute?

**Responding to comment about debugger:**

You need to step one more time, so that rows is initialized. Try the same thing in the servlet for the setAttribute statement, to see if dataList is null.

Comment: I saw it (about scriplet). Replay program with right srciplets, and you are right. It isn't solution of my problem.
Yes, I tried, but debug didn't say to me anything.